# Lock a table or rows to check a condition and insert a row

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to do the sequential steps:

1. to lock a table or specific rows (with a condition) for writing;
2. to check some rows with specific conditions;
3. if there are no rows with the conditions, add a new row
4. unlock

How can I do that in SQLAlchemy, Flask, PostgreSQL? What ways are correct?

Comment: Do it all in a transaction. This involves the code accessing the database. Then set the [transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/transaction-iso.html) level to the desired one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Flask-Sqlalchemy, so try to make adjustments.

You can use **with_for_update()** here. [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.with_for_update)

An example would be.

```
class TestTable(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "test_table"
    id = Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    filename = Column(db.String(1024))
    is_complete = Column(db.Boolean(), default=False, server_default="f")
```

You can lock them by doing:

```
for table in TestTable.query.with_for_update().filter_by(is_complete=False).all():
    # Example Check condition
    if table.filename != 'bar' and table.id >= 10:
       # Add a new row
       newtable = TestTable(filename='foo')
       db.session.add(newtable)

# Save and release lock
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that to be safe from race conditions, you need to use a transaction with `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level. Perform the whole operation in that transaction.